# objective-c singleton memory deallocation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

Should I somehow release shared object (on which singleton is based) when my application terminates if no garbage collector used (iPhone environment)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When an application exits, all its memory is released.  So it really does not matter if you release objects at all, so long as you don't use too much memory while running.

Even when the strategy changes in 4.0, a single small object won't have much impact; it will still be released along with the rest of the application when it terminates.

Comment: I'm sure I read somewhere that when an application knows it is going to close, it doesn't even bother doing the deallocs.  Anyway, it is unnecessary to release singletons unless you are relying on dealloc to dispose of some external resource.  If this is the case, redesign your class so you can explicitly dispose of the said external resource.

Comment: If you need to perform some sort of clean up when the application terminates, you can have the singleton object listen for `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`

Answer (score 4):

As an aside, you might find this useful:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Comment: I've already read about implementing a singleton. I think my question is more narrow. Anyway, thank you.