# How to dealloc and re-initialize a singleton class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to dealloc a class object ?

I have a singleton class "singleton.h" which has a single instance and we can make use of its properties in any other view controllers.

```
+(singleton *)sharedMethod{
static singleton *myInstance=nil;
if(myInstance ==nil){
myInstance=[[singleton alloc] init]; myInstace.str=@"hello";
}
return myInstance;
}
```

what I want to know is.., Is there any way by which we can dealloc the class object in any of our viewControllers...and then again creat an instance of a new singleton class.., I tried doing so.., Xcode throws an error "cannot dealloc class object".

Comment: `[[singleton sharedMethod] release];` `[singleton sharedMethod] = nil;` And then `[singleton sharedMethod]` will give you a new instance. EDIT: Fair enough, maybe that doesn't work. But the whole concept of deallocing a singleton is erroneous anyway. It shouldn't be done, ever.

Comment: @darvids0n: No, `[singleton sharedMethod] = nil;` doesn't even compile because your trying to assign an rvalue to an rvalue. Also, in a true singleton implementation deallocation is prevented by making `release` a NOP.

Comment: Maybe `*[singleton sharedMethod] = nil;`? Or `= NULL`/`= 0x0;`?

Comment: @darvids0n: No, still doesn't work, even though it would compile (with a warning and crash later on since the code doesn't do what you might think it does). It would only work if you'd have a method that returns the *address of the myInstance variable* that you can dereference.

Comment: By the very definition of singleton, you cannot replace a singleton with a new instance and meet the requirements of being a singleton.  You have no control over who might have stashed away a reference to the old instance, which should be a perfectly valid thing to do given the definition of singleton.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole point of a singleton is that you do not deallocate it ever. Other classes may safe a pointer to the instance, so if you want to replace it you'd get strange behavior or even crashes sometimes. So you shouldn't do it.

But it is possible, as long as you haven't overwritten the `release` and `retainCount` methods. But your cited error message seems to suggest you've done something along the lines of `[MyClass release];` which doesn't work, of course.

BTW, you seem to have `singleton` as a class name. Please try to stick to the coding conventions used by Apple to make your life and that of other people easier. Class names should always start with an uppercase character, method names should always start with a lowercase character.

Comment: Thanks for the response.., I just wrote down that example in stackoverflow so that it would make it easily understandable., No worries, Im using the Apple conventions in my code.  
I understand that the singleton class is created with the intention of not deallocating it throught the application. Just wanted to know.., if that is possible.

Answer (score 5):

declare

```
static YOUR_CLASS *shared = nil;
static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate; //very important for reinitialize.
```

use instance

```
+ (instancetype)shared  {
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        shared = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
```

reset

```
+ (void)reset{
    @synchronized(self) {
        shared = nil;
        oncePredicate = 0;
    }
}
```

you are good to go √

Answer (score 0):

It is very considerable if you don't dealloc the *singleton* class because it is not advised so till the complete excution of your application. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847875/objective-c-singleton-memory-deallocation) for more imformation. To reinitialize your *singleton* class you need to do the same as you did for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me out. Create a separate method for initializing the class.

```
@implementation SomeManager

static id sharedManager = nil;

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [SomeManager class]) {
        sharedManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
}

+ (id)sharedManager {
    return sharedManager;
}

@end
```

Source: http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=178